# how to ignore lat&lon NULLS while creating gmap markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, if-statement

I process a json url with e.g. 20 markers /adresses with the following code:

```
$.getJSON( jsonurl, function(data) { 
    $.each( data.rows, function(i, m) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',
            { 'icon': new google.maps.MarkerImage(m.a1_gifscan),
           'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.a1_lat, m.a1_lng),
           'bounds':true }).click(function()
```

When `a1_lat` and `a1_lng` are empty for 1 or more adresses, the gmap puts a marker on the equator position which ruins my scaling.

Question; how to ignore the empty lat lng values in my code?

Comment: When you say empty you mean empty string, null or undefined? Anyway, just an `if` inside the loop should help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solutions is to remove the bad data from your data source (database?).

I usually check something like this (not tested), it adds an alert so the bad data can be addressed:

```
var lat,lng;
if ((isNaN(lat=parseFloat(m.a1_lat))) ||
    (isNaN(lng=parseFloat(m.a1_lng)))) {
  alert("bad point:"+lat+","+lng);
} else {
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',
      { 'icon': new google.maps.MarkerImage(m.a1_gifscan),
     'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.a1_lat, m.a1_lng),
     'bounds':true }).click(function() {});     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `if (m.a1_lat && m.a1_lng)` as a test inside your iterative function. This will prevent the marker from being created if lat or lng are null.